# Delphi. Ошибка при инициализации MCI

Tags: delphi

Создаю видеопроигрыватель в Delphi 10.3.
При попытке воспроизвести видео, выдает ошибку: Ошибка при инициализации MCI.

Открываю файл .mp4.

С чем это может быть связано?

```
unit Unit13;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.MPlayer, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm13 = class(TForm)
    OpenDialog1: TOpenDialog;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    MediaPlayer1: TMediaPlayer;
    ScrollBar1: TScrollBar;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Panel2Resize(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ScrollBar1Scroll(Sender: TObject; ScrollCode: TScrollCode;
      var ScrollPos: Integer);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form13: TForm13;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses unit5, unit1;




procedure TForm13.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if (opendialog1.Execute) then
begin
  opendialog1.InitialDir:=ExtractFilePath(application.ExeName);
  timer1.Enabled:=false;
  with mediaplayer1 do begin
    FileName:=opendialog1.filename;
    Open;
    display:=panel2;
    DisplayRect:=panel1.ClientRect;
  end;
  scrollbar1.Max:=mediaplayer1.TrackLength[1];
  timer1.Enabled:=true;
end;

end;

procedure TForm13.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
mediaplayer1.Close;
form13.Close;
form1.Show;
end;

procedure TForm13.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label1.Parent:=scrollbar1;
  label1.Left:=round(scrollbar1.Width/2);
  label1.Top:=0;
end;

procedure TForm13.Panel2Resize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mediaplayer1.DisplayRect:=panel2.ClientRect;
end;

procedure TForm13.ScrollBar1Scroll(Sender: TObject; ScrollCode: TScrollCode;
  var ScrollPos: Integer);
begin
  mediaplayer1.Position:=scrollbar1.Position;
  mediaplayer1.play;
end;

procedure TForm13.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  scrollbar1.Position:= mediaplayer1.Position;
  label1.Caption:=formatfloat('0#.##', (scrollbar1.Position/scrollbar1.Max)*100);
  if mediaplayer1.Position=scrollbar1.Max then mediaplayer1.Stop;

end;

end.
```

Comment: я как минимум строку Open; подвинул бы на две строки ниже. То есть, вначале присваивание панели, а потом уже открытие

Comment: @KoVadim выдает всё ту же ошибку

Comment: тогда осталась вторая версия - нет нужного кодека.

Comment: @KoVadim а не расскажешь поподробнее?

Comment: Нет, не могу. Но стандартным плеером виндовым я бы попробовал бы